# Canon LBP2900B installation in 11.10

Tags: installation, 11.10, printing, canon

I need to install the Canon LBP2900B printers into my Ubuntu machines using 11.10 version. I have tried most of the queries online but could not able to find a solution for this issue. So could any body help me on this. and i need to share the printer as well on to other machines. so could some body help me on this i have tried to follow these instructions but it didnot worked for me

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find the Linux driver and the installation instructions here:

http://www.canon-europe.com/Support/Consumer_Products/products/printers/Laser/i-SENSYS_LBP2900.aspx?DLtcmuri=tcm:13-823414&page=1&type=download

You have to download the file, open the file with an archive manager, find the deb-directory, (maybe) make the files in that directory executable and run the shell script that is included.

I have a Canon Pixmania MP250. It works with the Linux driver from the canon-europe site.